# Clarification on reviews - 2

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for guidance on reviewing answers.  I forget whether this example was listed as a first answer or a low quality answer, but I've encountered several with this type of issue.  This example has been removed, but it was an answer to this question: [hdmi-connected-samsung-monitor-says-not-optimum-mode-recommended-mode-1920x1080](https://superuser.com/questions/802443/hdmi-connected-samsung-monitor-says-not-optimum-mode-recommended-mode-1920x108/848765#848765).  The gist was this:

The question asked about some image distortion on a monitor.  A new user posted an answer that was just a link to an external site, and several reviewers asked that a synopsis of the link contents be included in the answer.  However, it was the content of that link that worried me.  It was a blog or private web site (no refereeing or external comment), that addressed a similar issue, not necessarily even the same one.  It described a solution of soldering a resistor onto IC leads inside the monitor.  Even if that was an actual solution to the problem, it isn't something most users would be equipped to do and if it didn't void the warranty, the procedure would likely damage the IC and ruin the monitor.  Everything about the answer was dangerous, irresponsible, and it was from an unreliable source.  It didn't seem like the kind of answer SU would want to promote, so I flagged it for deletion.  Two questions:

- My understanding of the review process is that it is not about the content but about the nature of the answer.  Rather than censor content in the review, that should be done with downvotes and comments.  However, is there some point where it becomes a judgement call?  Was flagging for deletion appropriate?
- The answer was later deleted (not clear if this was based on multiple concurring reviews or moderator/high-rep user action).  On the flag status view, it lists the flag as "disputed".  What does that term mean (that multiple reviewers didn't make the same recommendation for disposition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question asked about some image distortion on a monitor. A new user posted an answer that was just a link to an external site, and several reviewers asked that a synopsis of the link contents be included in the answer.

That's the main reason for deleting such a post.

[image]

We want the solution to be posted here, on the site, rather than behind a link to an external resource. Especially with private pages, it just happens too often that these links break at some point.

> Everything about the answer was dangerous, irresponsible, and it was from an unreliable source. It didn't seem like the kind of answer SU would want to promote, so I flagged it for deletion.
>
> (…) Rather than censor content in the review, that should be done with downvotes and comments. However, is there some point where it becomes a judgement call? Was flagging for deletion appropriate?

Even if you think the answer promotes something dangerous or irresponsible, that's generally not a valid reason to request deletion. Moderators should never have to evaluate such technical aspects (unless they're blatantly obvious). Answers should be deleted when they're:

- not answering a question at all. It actually does not matter *which* question, at this point, unless it's obvious—like posting a cooking recipe here.
- unsalvageable through editing
- link-only and not easy to fix by reviewing or copy-pasting an essential piece of the original source

As for the judgement call on something having to be removed because it's dangerous, there's an [older post already](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1833/should-potentially-dangerous-answers-be-flagged-deleted), but it's a little bit of an extreme example with `rm -rf /` being mentioned. You'd rarely do that in good faith.

I would suggest that if you think an answer suggests something mildly dangerous (e.g. something that could brick your device, voiding the warranty, etc.), you leave a comment to that effect. A professional user may wish to ignore that warning. We can't delete everything that *might* cause issues for someone. In principle, any command line example with `sudo` could wreak havoc on a system if not typed correctly.

Of course, posts with links to pirated software, malware, dubious sites, etc. should be flagged for closer inspection.

> On the flag status view, it lists the flag as "disputed". What does that term mean (that multiple reviewers didn't make the same recommendation for disposition)?

The post went through review, where it received more *delete* votes than *looks good*. This raises an automatic flag for moderators.

I think that this auto flag alone results in a a *very low quality* flag being resolved as *disputed*. At least when I deleted the post, both your flag and the auto-flag got cleared at the same time.

[image]