# What to do when new user's answer is mischievous / mildly malicious

Tags: discussion, new-users

While reviewing the *First Posts* queue, I came across [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/917212/247588) where the new user recommends a keyboard short-cut which closes the current window. I down-voted the answer and left a comment.

I searched for relevant posts on meta and [Should potentially “Dangerous” answers be flagged/deleted?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1833/should-potentially-dangerous-answers-be-flagged-deleted/1834) is the closest I could find. The consensus was to flag such posts for the moderator's attention.

However, I don't think this answer is actually dangerous; an alert user wouldn't be caught out by it and it's not the end of the world if the window did close since AFAIK Chrome keeps track of closed tabs and windows.

I'm wary of wasting a moderators' time but I thought I'd post here to see what other super users think.

Comment: Just flag it. Don't worry about wasting moderators' time. The flag queue is usually pretty empty.

Comment: @allquixotic That's not a valid reason for flagging unnecessarily. The queue is often empty *because* things like this aren't flagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is not dangerous in any way, but simply a wrong answer, please do not flag it.

Down voting and leaving a comment is the way to go here.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the feedback.